# How to change div background on dragover when also contains image

Tags: css

I have a dropzone where user can drop an image, it has some associated CSS that makes the dropzone background go grey as they drag the image, giving a visual cue.

Html

```
   <div>
        <figure>
            <div id="dropzone">
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#dropzone {
  border: 3px solid black;
  min-width:300px; 
  min-height:100px;
  max-width:300px; 
  max-height:100px;
}

#dropzone.dragover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

But I don't want the dropzone to be empty I would like it to have a starting image (which says something like 'Drop Files Here')

```
   <div>
        <figure>
            <div id="dropzone">
               <img src="dropzone.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

and if I add this, then the dropzone doesnt grey out when drag an image over, how do I fix this?

Comment: You'd better to set background via `background-image` without `img` element inside `<div id="dropzone">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the background image with CSS property [background-image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/)

```
#dropzone{
  background-image: url(path/to/your/image);
  /* rest of the css goes here*/
}
```

```css
#dropzone {
  border: 3px solid black;
  min-width:300px; 
  min-height:100px;
  max-width:300px; 
  max-height:100px;
  background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/577775/pexels-photo-577775.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto;
}

#dropzone.dragover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <figure>
        <div id="dropzone">
        </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`opacity`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity) on the `dropzone`.

```
#dropzone.dragover {opacity:0.5}
```

Because `background` is only the background-color of the element.

Comment: Thanks that works, but the background option works better

Answer (score 1):

I got two solutions for you:

First I display the image as a `background-image` and then I filter it in the fist solution to be grayscale ([More about `filter` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)) and in the second solution I just overwrite the background to just be gray.

```css
#dropzone1,
#dropzone2 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto;
}

#dropzone1:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#dropzone2:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <div id="dropzone1">
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>

<div>
  <figure>
    <div id="dropzone2">
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```